# Keep repeating values from left table blank in sql left join

Tags: sql

table 1

| EmployeeId | Employee Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Employee1 |
| 2 | Employee2 |

table2

| EmployeeId | Leave Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/08/2021 |
| 2 | 01/08/2021 |
| 1 | 02/08/2021 |
| 3 | 03/08/2021 |
| 1 | 04/08/2021 |
| 2 | 05/08/2021 |

I have tried by joining the table like this

```
select EmployeeId, LeaveDate from 
Table1
JOIN table 2 on table1.EmplaoyeeId = table2.EmployeeId
order by EmployeeId
```

But getting the output like this

| EmployeeId | LeaveDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/08/2021 |
| 1 | 02/08/2021 |
| 1 | 04/08/2021 |
| 2 | 05/08/2021 |
| 2 | 01/08/2021 |
| 3 | 03/08/2021 |

Desired result

| EmployeeId | LeaveDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/08/2021 |
|  | 02/08/2021 |
|  | 04/08/2021 |
| 2 | 01/08/2021 |
|  | 05/08/2021 |
| 3 | 03/08/2021 |

I need to print left tables data for once and for the rest matching rows it should be empty.

Comment: Don't do that in SQL. Do that in your program logic

Comment: I am with juergen d here. This is something you shouldn't do in SQL. While it is possible and even simple (using `LAG` and `CASE WHEN`), display issues should be dealt with in your app. SQL is meant to give you the data. And leave date 02/08/2021 belongs to employee 1, not to employee NULL.

Comment: you should change this in your reporting structure of website code instead of achieving on sql

Comment: Please only tag the DBMS you are using. Is it SQL Server or SQLite? On a side note: You don't need tale1 in that query. All the data needed is present in table2.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner can you please briefly explain how can I achieve on the app side? It will take more time to loop over all the rows and manually erasing the values

Comment: Well, what does an app do? It sends the SQL to the DBMS. The DBMS sends back the data. The app checks what columns to deal with and then fetches the first row from the result set. It reads value by value and fills an array or grid with the data. Then it fetches the next row and so on until there is no more row in the result set. It doesn't seem to difficult to insert a blank in the array or grid instead of the value now and then. And if your app's database library fills a grid or array with one single command? Well, yes, then loop through it. Should be very few lines and quite quick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve that with a single query, but this should work for you

```
;WITH CTE
AS(
select 
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY EmployeeId,LeaveDate),
    EmployeeId, 
    LeaveDate 
    from Table1
        JOIN Table2 
            on table1.EmplaoyeeId = table2.EmployeeId
)
SELECT  
    EmployeeId = CASE RN 
                    WHEN 1 THEN EmployeeId END, 
    LeaveDate 
    FROM CTE
        ORDER BY 
            EmployeeId,RN
```

Comment: This *is* a single query :-) And if you refer to a query without a subquery, well, then simply apply `CASE WHEN` directly on `ROW_NUMBER` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

For your desired results, you don't need a `join`, so I'll remove it.  However, that does not affect the answer.  You just need to use `row_number()` and be sure that the final `order by` matches the `order by` in `row_number()`:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by t2.EmployeeId order by t2.LeaveDate) = 1
             then t2.EmployeeId
        end) as EmployeeId,
       t2.LeaveDate
from table2 t2
order by t2.EmployeeId, t2.LeaveDate;
```

Note though that this type of operation is often handled in the presentation layer rather than in the database.